# Make elementary OS freya boot in 20 seconds

Tags: boot, kernel, microsoft-windows

My laptop is dual-booting Windows 10 and elementary OS.Windows 10 boots to the desktop (Chrome opens instantly)  in just 20 seconds (including POST which is only 1 sec) while elementary OS Freya takes about one minute and another 3 seconds to open Chrome.

How can I get fast boot times with elementary OS.

My laptop is a HP Pavilion g7 2269wm with 500GB HDD.

Also there is a lot of time wasted before the elementary logo (about 5 seconds) with no disk activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Windows you probably have fastboot enabled, which uses a sort of hibernation to boot faster.

If so, those times make sense: in my case elementary OS boots in around 30 seconds, whereas Windows 10 takes around 15 with fastboot (or around a minute without).

Comment: Do you have a SSD

Comment: No, standard HDD

Comment: I have done some optimizing and now I get around 40 seconds.I am wondering if Linux has kernel hibernation feature like Windows 8 and newer

Comment: Not really, although you can enable hibernation. It can be messy however, on my PC I could hibernate just fine as many times as I wanted, but then shutting down would freeze everything.

Comment: I mean can we have kernel hibernation.